# Confusion regarding batch size

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

If we have 500 images and we want to set batch size=20 so 500/20= 25 samples in each batch and epoch size is 5 so each epoch 25 sample will be given to model as forward pass and update weights right? My question is after given 25 samples and what about next epoch same 25 samples are given or other 25 samples from dataset which were not shown to model?

Comment: No, the batch size is the number of samples in each batch. So you would have 25 batches of size 20, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer I was considering batch size mean number of batches but now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

- Batch size: how many samples are there in each batch [20]
- Epoch: period required for all samples to be consumed [500 samples, 25 batches]

Overall typically it will look like this:

```
    20       20              20
  [ BATCH1][ BATCH2] ..... [ BATCH25]           [ BATCH1][ BATCH2] ..... [ BATCH25] 
  [           EPOCH1                ] [SHUFFLE] [           EPOCH2                ] 
              500
```

Thus you will get 25 batches, each of 20 samples, which will form a single epoch of 500 samples, when the split will get reshuffled and new epochs starts, again consisting of 25 (now different) batches.